# notify when terminal output added

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, notifications

It would be helpful to know if there's a way to get notified e.g. a sound, or better a notification popup, when a line is added to the terminal output.

e.g. `while true; do; sleep 5; echo "notify"; done`. I would like to be notified everytime `notify` is shown on terminal.

I tried [iterm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016716/how-do-i-make-iterm-terminal-notify-me-when-a-job-process-is-complete) but it only notfies when command is completed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-bell.html.en + `echo -e "\a"`

Comment: How should the notification look like? For instance a change in the terminal tab?

Comment: a sound would be best